# What will the tex command for the following image?

Tags: drop-cap

How can I produce the below image in LaTEX. To be specific look at the starting word of the paragraph. I dont want to produce that word, but the format in which the paragraph is produced looks nice. I hope people understand what I want.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's known as a drop cap there are several packages which help with that and discussion on this site  see http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=drop+cap

Comment: An alternative name is 'lettrine' (from the French): there is a package by this name and also a [tag:lettrine] tag on the site. (There's a more general [tag:drop-cap] tag too, which I've added to the question).

Comment: OK, based on the OP's comment I'll close.